# Color Change in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I am completely new to wpf and MVVM. I have created a code which binds the values from the listView to the Textbox and Viceversa.
The data to the list view is sent from the database.
Now I would like to change the color of the row in the list view when text in the textbox is updated.
I also have similar connection of two checkboxes with the same listview. Could you please help since I could not find a correct solution for the same.
Below is my code:

```
<UserControl>
    

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,20,20,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="236"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="494"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Mitarbeiter Status" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
    <TextBox  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Width="261" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=EmployeeStatusListView, Path=SelectedItem.Status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"/>
    <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="IsAdmin" Margin="0,10,0,10"  IsChecked="{Binding ElementName =EmployeeStatusListView, Path=SelectedItem.IsAdmin,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True }"/>
    <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="IsMandatory" Margin="0,10,0,10" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName =EmployeeStatusListView, Path=SelectedItem.IsMandatory,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>


    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,10" >
        <Button Width="100" Content="Hinzufugen" Command="{Binding Path=AddCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=EmployeeStatusListView ,Path=SelectedItem}" Margin="100,10,30,0"/>
        <Button  Width="90" Content="Update"  Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=EmployeeStatusListView,  Path=SelectedItem}" Height="30" Margin="20,10,30,0" />
        <Button  Width="90" Content="Löschen" Command="{Binding Path=DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=EmployeeStatusListView,  Path=SelectedItem}"  Height="30" Margin="20,10,30,0" />
    </StackPanel>
    
<ListView SelectedItem="EmployeeStatusSelect" SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Name="EmployeeStatusListView" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeStatusList}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.502,0.66" Margin="0,20,0,-19" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Mitarbeiter Admin Nummer " Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsAdmin}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Mitarbeiter Status " Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Mandantory " Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsMandatory, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                
            </GridView>
            
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: "When the text is updated, can you please define the case. For exemple it changes when the first char is typed or when the input is over. Does it change once or multiple times ?

Comment: You might find my datagrid sample interesting. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WPF-Highlight-Changed-a77976d4

Comment: Is it entity framework? If it is you can query EF if the object is modified since loaded from db.

Comment: @XimazeC , Yeah I would like the data in the ListView to be updated in a different color as soon as the first letter in the textbox is modified. Once I click on the update button , then the color of the row in the ListView should be black(original color). Basically any modification needs to be reflected till it is updated.

Comment: It's a bad idea to retain a dbcontext in memory and retain change tracking. You should instantiate dbcontext with a using and dispose it straight after you get your dats. Entity data should be copied to viewmodels for ui. Copied back to model instances to update the database.

Comment: Yes you are right. In some cases this is not the way. But in this case it looks like a simple administration tool for a database table. I worked with datasets for 15 years. I did not like them but for cases like this they were perfect. No copying data around and intruducing errors and bugs, no rebuild of a change tracker, data mappers, ... just works and is easy,

Comment: @Andy The data is updated into the database only on the click of update and it is done exactly how you mentioned. The change in listview is only temporary when updated in textbox and that is the reason i wanted to show it in a different color.